# How to fitting EELS background for two window

Tags: dm-script

The dm-script provide the function to fitting the exponential background, such as:

```
image src := GetFrontImage()
number bEs = 340 // eV
number bEe = 390 // eV
image signal := EELSSubtractPowerLawBackground(src, bEs, bEe)
```

[image]

However, for the weak signal, we would want to improve the S/N ratio by fitting two window background, such as:
[image]

Is anyone knows how to fit this kind of background through script?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to BmyGuest, but I would like to build a fully automatic procedure.
Fortunately, I found a solution that is simple to write down the script.
Here is the code:

```
// reference:
// https://towardsdatascience.com/mathematics-for-machine-learning-linear-regression-least-square-regression-de09cf53757c
// key information:
// y = mx + b
// where m = sum ((xdata-xmean)*(ydata-ymean)) / sum ((xdata-xmean)**2)
//       b = ymean - m*xmean

class FittingTwoWindowBkg : object {
    FittingTwoWindowBkg(object self) {
        Result("Script object 'FittingTwoWindowBkg' ["+self.ScriptObjectGetID().hex()+"] constructed.\n");
    };
    
    ~FittingTwoWindowBkg(object self) {
        Result("Script object 'FittingTwoWindowBkg' ["+self.ScriptObjectGetID().hex()+"] destructed.\n");
    };
    
    image TwoWindowBkgFitting(object self, image src, number Eng1, number Rng1, number Eng2, number Rng2) {
        number Eorignal = src.ImageGetDimensionOrigin(2)
        number Estep = src.ImageGetDimensionScale(2)
        number sx, sy, sz
        src.Get3DSize(sx, sy, sz)
        
        image axis = src.ImageClone()
        axis = iplane*Estep + Eorignal
        axis.SetName("Energy axis")
        
        // the power law bkg I = A E^-r can be simplified to
        // the linear formula by : log(I) = -r*log(E) + log(A)
        image data = src.ImageClone()
        data = log(data)
        data.SetName("log SI")
        
        number ch1 = trunc((Eng1-Eorignal)/Estep)
        number r1= trunc(Rng1/Estep)
        number ch2 = trunc((Eng2-Eorignal)/Estep)
        number r2= trunc(Rng2/Estep)
        number nsz = r1+r2
        
        // prepare for regression
        image xdata := RealImage("xdata",4,sx,sy, nsz)
        xdata.Slice3(0,0,0,0,sx,1,1,sy,1,2,r1,1) = axis.Slice3(0,0,ch1,0,sx,1,1,sy,1,2,r1,1)
        xdata.Slice3(0,0,r1,0,sx,1,1,sy,1,2,r2,1) = axis.Slice3(0,0,ch2,0,sx,1,1,sy,1,2,r2,1)
        
        image ydata := RealImage("ydata",4,sx,sy, nsz)
        ydata.Slice3(0,0,0,0,sx,1,1,sy,1,2,r1,1) = data.Slice3(0,0,ch1,0,sx,1,1,sy,1,2,r1,1)
        ydata.Slice3(0,0,r1,0,sx,1,1,sy,1,2,r2,1) = data.Slice3(0,0,ch2,0,sx,1,1,sy,1,2,r2,1)
        
        image xmean := RealImage("xmean",4,sx,sy, nsz)
        image ymean := RealImage("ymean",4,sx,sy, nsz)
        for (number i=0; i<nsz; i++) {
            // to repeat the mean value as a 3d stack
            // the sum value of each pixel can be rapidly done by the Project function
            xmean.Slice2(0,0,i,0,sx,1,1,sy,1) = Project(xdata,2) / nsz
            ymean.Slice2(0,0,i,0,sx,1,1,sy,1) = Project(ydata,2) / nsz
        };
        
        // do regression
        image m = Project((xdata-xmean)*(ydata-ymean), 2) / Project((xdata-xmean)**2, 2)
        image b = ymean[icol,irow,0] - m*xmean[icol,irow,0]
        
        // to apply y=mx+b to all the planes
        image bkg := src.ImageClone()
        for (number i=0; i<sz; i++) {
            bkg.Slice2(0,0,i,0,sx,1,1,sy,1) = m*axis.Slice2(0,0,i,0,sx,1,1,sy,1)+b
        };
        
        // reconstruct to the power law bkg
        bkg = exp(bkg)
        
        return bkg
    };
    
}

{
    Object FTW = Alloc(FittingTwoWindowBkg)
    number Eng1 = 1500      // eV, 1st Energy of fitting window
    number Rng1 = 200       // eV, fitting range of 1st window
    number Eng2 = 2600      // eV, 2nd Energy of fitting window
    number Rng2 = 200       // eV, fitting range of 2nd window
    image src := GetFrontImage()
    image bkg := FTW.TwoWindowBkgFitting(src, Eng1, Rng1, Eng2, Rng2)
    bkg.ShowImage()
};
```

Comment: Yes, doing the math yourself is always an option ;c)  I like your solution. Can you post your 2nd question separately, please?
So that it serves as separate Q&A and is easier to link-to/search-for on StackOverflow.
I'm also not 100% sure I understood the additional question as posted. Generally speaking, using for & sliceN is the fasted way in scripting though, unless a dedicated command exist for your task. If "Project( )" is the same restult for all i, you want to do it outside the loop though!

Comment: No problem, I will post the question later on.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there doesn't exist an explicit command for this.
However, one can work around this, by mimicking what one would do manually: adding ROIs in order to the display.

The following script does what you want, but it does require the spectrum to be displayed and will remove other ROIs on it.

```c
number b1Es = 400 // eV
number b1Ee = 510 // eV
number b2Es = 800 // eV
number b2Ee = 850 // eV

image src := GetFrontImage()
imageDisplay disp = src.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)     // Script requires spectrum to be displayed

// Need to convert range values into channels by calibration 
number scale, origin
string units
src.ImageGetDimensionCalibration(0,origin,scale,units,0)
if ( units != "eV" ) Throw( "Spectrum not calibrated in eV" )
number b1Es_ch = trunc( (b1Es - origin)/scale )
number b1Ee_ch = trunc( (b1Ee - origin)/scale )
number b2Es_ch = trunc( (b2Es - origin)/scale )
number b2Ee_ch = trunc( (b2Ee - origin)/scale )

// Remove any existing ROIs on the spectrum
while( disp.ImageDisplayCountROIS() )
    disp.ImageDisplayDeleteROI( disp.ImageDisplayGetRoi(0))

ROI bkgr1 = NewROI()
bkgr1.ROISetRange(b1Es_ch,b1Ee_ch)

ROI sigr = NewROI()
sigr.ROISetRange(b1Ee_ch,b2Es_ch)

ROI bkgr2 = NewROI()
bkgr2.ROISetRange(b2Es_ch,b2Ee_ch)

// Add ROIs in order (like when adding by mouse) 
disp.ImageDisplayAddROI(bkgr1)  // BACKGROUND 1
disp.ImageDisplayAddROI(sigr)   // SIGNAL
disp.ImageDisplayAddROI(bkgr2)  // BACKGROUND 2 (and more...)

// Optionally: Change background model away from default 
// ChooseMenuItem( "EELS", "Background Model", "Linear" )

image signal := src{"Edge"}.ImageClone()    // copy edge-slice

// Remove ROIs again (cleanup)
while( disp.ImageDisplayCountROIS() )
    disp.ImageDisplayDeleteROI( disp.ImageDisplayGetRoi(0))

// Show "signal"
signal.ShowImage()
```